# How to restore or recreate the deleted gitweb folder

Tags: restore, git

I'm not sure what to do. It contained gitweb.cgi and one other file that I'm not sure of. My configuration files are still secure, but I can't seem to figure out how to simply restore the /git/ folder in the webroot (I'm pretty sure gitweb.cgi is all I need). I'm having trouble re`make`ing the program for that file but can't find a download anywhere.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0):

If it was installed via a package, just reinstall that package.  If you built it yourself, [just rebuild it](http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/INSTALL).